# Jackson - mapping single json key to multiple variable

Tags: java, json, jackson

With fasterxml jackson  mapper, getting below exception while try to map the same json key to multiple variable in pojo. But some usecase requires the mapping, so is there any work option to overcome this, with addressing any change in pojo.

**Exception:**

```
Conflicting setter definitions for property "vno"
```

**json :**

```
{"vno":"123556"}
```

**pojo:**

```
@JsonProperty(value="vno")
public String getVno(String vno)

@JsonProperty(value="vno")
public String getIdno(String idno)
```

Comment: `getVno(String vno)` and `getIdno(String idno)` are really confusing. What are they supposed to be? Fields? Getters? Setters?

Comment: Let me know if my solution works for you.

Comment: Do you remember how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

You cannot have two `vno` mapped properties in your POJO:

```java
@JsonProperty(value = "vno")
public void setVno(String vno) {
    ...
}

@JsonProperty(value = "vno")
public void setIdno(String idno) {
    ...
}
```

### Dealing with getters

What you can do is:

- Create a method annotated with [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) to decide which value will be returned for the `vno` property.
- Annotate the other getter methods with [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

For more details, see the following piece of code:

```java
@JsonIgnore
public String getVno() {
    ...
}

@JsonIgnore
public String getIdno() {
    ...
}

@JsonProperty(value = "vno")
public String getValueForVnoProperty() {
    // Decide which value will be returned
    ...
}
```

### Dealing with setters

Simmilary to the approach mentioned above, you can have the following:

- Create a method annotated with [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) to decide in which property the value of the `vno` property will be set.
- Annotate the other setter methods with [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

See the following piece of code:

```java
@JsonIgnore
public void setVno(String vno) {
    ...
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setIdno(String idno) {
    ...
}

@JsonProperty(value = "vno")
public void setValueForVnoProperty(String value) {
    // Decide in which property the value will be set
    ...
}
```